# How does Targum on Tehillim 51:7 reconcile with Yishai being pure? Also interested in other aspects of the verse

Tags: tehilim-psalms, king-david, eve-chava

The verse states, "Behold, with iniquity I was formed, and with sin my mother conceived me. Most the commentaries are not available in english (https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Tehillim/51.6#e1n6). Some explain about David ha-melech's mother, and some about his father. Onkelos in the Targum comments, "Behold, in iniquities my father thought to create me; and in the sin of the evil impulse my mother conceived me." If "father" refers to Yishai, how can we reconcile that with Shabbat 55b which says Yishai had no sin or flaw of his own? If "father" referred to Hashem, how could Hashem create in iniquity, unless it should be read that Hashem of course created with purity, but *created David with iniquity in him* in order to give him an obstacle to overcome to earn his reward? And similar questions for the mother aspect of the interpretation on any levels it could apply (about Nitzevet, about Eve, and if applicable about the Shechinah, which I'm not saying it is, just that I'd like to learn those interpretations too *if* they exist).

Another midrash, google translates as "Both in my sinful space and in G-d - the tendency to sin and iniquity is natural in man." You cannot go off google translations, sometimes they are correct, sometimes they make huge errors that have heretical implications. I would discount any translation that flirted with the idea of sin in G-d as heretical and wrong, but since some texts do flirt with the idea of illicit desire within G-d, I can't know if it's the translation or if this commentary is exploring a similar idea? So I am asking for help to learn the key concepts from the most instructive commentaries on this verse, whether from the ones available in english on altorah or elsewhere. For example they don't have many of the major kabbalists there, but that is not my focus, since if there are non-kabbalists with great interpretations elsewhere, I am just as interested in those. In general I am always searching for the interpretations that mean the most to me and expand my scope of contemplation the most (part of the process of understanding but that is a much longer process). I seem to connect most with the more philosophic and (at first) counter-intuitive interpretations which are often found with the kabbalists, thus my interest, but many times these come from non-kabbalists also, or sometimes I connect to the peshat or pemez more than the derash or sod. It just depends on a case by case basis, which is why I always want to know the full scope of the interpretations, from the most "simple" explanations to the most complex.

Comment: See the story of the controversy surrounding David's birth here: https://www.chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/280331/jewish/Nitzevet-Mother-of-David.htm . A connection could be made from that to being conceived in iniquity.

Comment: @Menachem Thank you very much. I was aware of most of that, and I'm still left with many questions. How can the iniquity be of the father, Yishai, for wanting to lay with the maidservant, if he had no iniquity in him? In any case even if one made the case that his intent was iniquitous, he was not successful in his intent, and still ended up begetting David with his wife, which is not iniquity. Perhaps you could argue he was thinking of the wrong woman during the intercourse, and that this had an effect, but I would need to see it in midrash.

Comment: @Menachem The most direct way to answer about iniquity of David's father is prob Shmuel 2 17:25, but my understanding was always that Yishai was so called because he rectified the sin of the nachash, not that he is like it himself. I mean he is an example of anti-nachash if anything based on midrashim I learned. But if there are different midrashim that say he did have great sin within him to warrant that name in a direct sense then it would answer this. It would just be so opposite of other midrashim that it seems unlikely, but maybe even disagreements that large are not unheard of/impossible

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of the source of the Targum quoted by Alhatorah. The official Targum quoted in the Hebrew does not mention his father. (Btw, Onkelos only translated the Pentateuch. Yonasan ben Uziel translated Prophets. The Targum to Writings is of uncertain authorship.) However, even if that is a valid Targum, your question is already answered from a different angle:

See the [Maharsha](https://shas.alhatorah.org/Full/Shabbat/55b.3#e0n6) there who is responding to a similar question from Tosafos:

> ארבעה מתו בעטיו של נחש – והא דכתיב (קהלת ז) כי אדם אין צדיק בארץ וגו׳

that the verse in Ecclesiastes 7 says explicitly that there is no man without sin.

He answers that the everyone has some sin, but the Gemara means that the sin of Yishai and the others was not great enough to deserve death, so they only died as a result of the sin of Adam.

This also answers your question. The sin of Yishai in conceiving David was not enough for him to die. After all, laying with the maidservant was not technically forbidden, and thus while it may have been a failing (the literal translation of חטא means to be missing something) it was not a sin that deserved death.

Comment: Thanks @N.T! Just to be clear, you're referring to that Yishai thought he was lying with the maidservant, or is there a midrash that David ha Melech is actually the son of someone other than Avigail?

Comment: The former. Even if Yishai had gone through with it, it would not have been technically forbidden. But he didn't, and fathered David with Avigail.

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, put a check to let people know.

Comment: Last time I did that it didnt let me put a check on any other answers. Your answer is great, but there are an unknown (to me) number of other explanations judging from the many commentaries in Hebrew only (unless they are all the same), plus probably ones not present on altorah, that I also want to hear, and if I put the check it seems to close the question.

Is there a way to put the check but still have it open for more answers?

Comment: See because when I think about it, there must be deeper mysteries about Yishai being called Nachash just that he had a little bit of sin in him like everyone. Then why isn't everyone called nachash? He had a little bit still *less* than others so why that name? And David ha melech's lineage from Moav...

Here's another angle to approach the question. Why did David have no years of his own to live, and Adam had to give him 70? Was that related to iniquity that he wasn't given his own years to live? I want to learn all these answers and more, whatever answers there are on this concept.

Comment: You can uncheck it later, if a better answer comes along, AFAIK.  Yishai is called Nachash because that's the ONLY reason he had to die. This is similar to Rambam's description of why only some halachos are called "Halacha from Moshe from Sinai" when they all are: they are only able to be justified by their provenance from Sinai, so they don't fit into smaller categories, and are referred to by the name for the overall category.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Please review my edit and let me know if you think that is a good way to do it or not. Your answer is great, I just want to learn more interpretations. There are so many great Rabbis since Matan Torah, there must be dozens of authorative commentaries on the verse at least, maybe hundreds. If I remember you have an affinity for the Gra, what was his interpretation of this verse? And then I wont ask you specifically any others, but in general the question is asking, what about Rabbi D'Eliezer? What about the Ben Ish Chai? What about Rambam? What about... etc etc etc.

Comment: It's not really fair to other users to edit your question into a follow-up question, because then they miss out on the original interaction. I would either ask a follow-up question separately, or fit it in the comments. Your edited question could make a good chat room, in this case.

Comment: As to what you actually wrote, it's admirable how much you want to learn. In your case, the better road could be to spend some time at a yeshiva like Ohr Sameiach or Aish HaTorah to get the skills to learn this on your own. A good temporary resource could be the Artscroll Tehillim (2 vol.) You could easily fill a large bookcase with the many commentaries written on Tehillim. Most of the commentaries in the classic Mikraos Gedolos understand "sin" in this context to refer to physical lust of Yishai. Technically though, lust is not a sin if it is not misused, similar to hunger.

Comment: I meant in your answer, I edited a disclaimer that "I awarded this the winning answer, but I'm also interested in more answers so don't think that just because this has a winning answer already, the original question is closed," sort of thing. I dont think I added new questions in that edit, but in the comments here I asked about the Gra etc, just as examples of how the original question was searching out more answers. The first paragraph mentions I'd like to learn interpretations about Hashem, Yishai, Adam, Eve, Nitzevet, Shechinah, etc. 

Its a broad question. Maybe I should have...

Comment: titled it "please post as many commentaries as possible, translated into english, for this verse," and that would have been a better title, since that's essentially what I was looking for, but I also wanted to specify the difficulties in the verse and what I was hoping to learn from those commentaries, so that people could reply with a combination of quotes from commentaries but also summaries of their own.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that's great. By skills do you mean just reading more commentaries on my own, or what?

Ohr Sameiach, is that online Yeshiva? I dont live in Eretz Yisrael. As for Aish, I have read many articles on their website, chabad.org, some on Gal Einei, and many others. There is so much quantity that it would be a big help if you could let me know what specifically you would recommend? 

I cant figure out how to move this to chat. I know someone told me before but I forgot. Google search for stackexchange says only mods can do it, or to spam until it prompts you.

Comment: By skills, I mean the ability to understand primary sources on your own. And I do mean actually going to Israel to study. Or to an American yeshiva or program geared to your level.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Most the commentaries on AlTorah for this verse are not available in english, and that is a common problem for non-Hebrew speakers. Sefaria and AlTorah are great but they are only fulfilling like 5% their potential (for non-Hebrew speakers) because most Commentaries are not translated, even ones available in Artscroll in english are not easily navigable on AlTorah and Sefaria. Maybe I should try their app? Except they might not have all the navigation to everything that AlTorah and Sefaria do. I still want to learn Hebrew but it's not working out how I planned so far.

Comment: As far as my ability to comprehend on my own even the primary sources that are available to me now in a language I speak, are you still thinking about the ZA prayer post? That wasn't a comprehension issue but an issue of being taught that by someone I thought knew the material who may have been wrong, and I stumbled on a couple weeks ago that I'd also read it from Gershom Scholem which jogged my memory. Normally I wouldnt have trusted that by itself but since I also heard it (in some sense) from someone learning to be a Rabbi, I did, plus was trying to make a comparison for the question.

Comment: And I probably learned it somewhere else kosher years ago. There are so many different variations and terminology changes over the centuries, and I dont think it was systemized so clearly until Arizal, which was one of the last sages I started to learn. I still have a lot to learn, it just takes time, but I ask the questions best I can at my current level. I confess since that ZA comment happened I have felt a bit ashamed and worried that people will always think of me as someone who miscomprehended clear material in their post right after joining the forum, but I hope not.I want to post

Comment: I want to post the quote from Scholem, not to imply he is a reliable source, or to suggest you were wrong and I was right, but only to clear my name a little bit as far as the idea that I struggle to comprehend verses on my own beyond most people. Memory is an issue, yes, although in this case I remembered the core of the teaching accurately (maybe only because it was reinforced by at least one other, but still). Quote in next comment since no space here.

Comment: *(Luria's) three hymns for the three Sabbath meals are directed to the mystical configurations of (G-d): the "Holy Ancient One," the Zeir Anpin, and the Shekhinah ... In these hymns, then, Luria appears to address the Partsufim as separate personalities. This is an extreme attitude.* Major Trends in Jewish Mysticism page 271.

I know he's not a kosher source, and I dont know if he's right about this or not. But I do think think expecting someone still just learning, and formulating questions best they can, to make less mistakes than a top academic of Kabbalah is not realistic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137332/discussion-between-shipbuilding-and-n-t).